# Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count

Tags: objective-c

Since upgrading to Lion and consequently to XCode 4.1

I get dozens of "potential memory leak" when running the Analyzer.

I would typically use a property list like so:

```
@synthesize indexPath = _indexPath;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    self.indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
    [_indexPath release];
    return self;
}
```

and in dealloc() method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_indexPath release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now, analyze will show me the dreaded blue message on self.indexPath telling me that there's a leak. When there's obviously none.

How do you allocate and format your code so XCode doesn't believe it's leaking? (while keeping the property alias self.var vs _var)

Thank you...

Comment: I tried various things such as: [self.indexPath release];

but then I get "incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller."

Comment: In my example, I showed a case where it's an init method, but I use this code structure consistently across my projects. Doing self.var = ... takes care of deallocating any previous allocated instance. So doing _var = [[ClassName alloc] init]; isn't a suitable generic approach

Comment: Following everyone's comments: here is my solution: self.var = nil; _var = [[ClassName alloc] init]; this will work in a similar way no matter the context.

Comment: `self.var = …` isn't only for releasing the old value; it also retains/copies and assigns the new value. If you autorelease the object you get from `init`, you can assign it directly to the property, without having to assign `nil` to the property first or assign directly to the ivar afterward. This makes it a one-liner that's much clearer than your frankly odd (at best, hyperoptimized) two-liner.

Comment: As a long time embedded developer, not making an object auto-released is far more elegant to me: doing otherwise is both slower and memory-footprint wise inefficient.

Comment: I suggest adopting ARC as soon as possible, then. All releases happen implicitly, and `autorelease` as it existed before ARC is dead, replaced with the `@autoreleasepool` memory-scoping statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers already explain the problem in depth, anyway these are some common patterns that you can use to avoid this error:

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
self.indexPath = ip;
/* ... */
[ip release];
```

```
indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
```

```
self.indexPath = [[[NSIndexPath alloc] init] autorelease];
```

```
self.indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:...];
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it. But that line is probably tricking the analyzer, so I'll leave this question here as "common alternatives".

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment, really I'm looking at something generic enough so it uses the same coding structure for within an init method, or not. Using self.var takes care of deallocating any memory if required

Comment: @Kendall: I assume the Analyzer stumbles over the fact that he releases the ivar and not some local variable. It probably doesn't recognize the ivar is the backing ivar for the property.

Comment: @Rudy: that's what I think is happening as well, it doesn't know that self is self in that case because it can change...

Comment: @jyavenard anywhere else but the init method I would agree with you, but in init you are supposed to stay away from accessors to avoid firing KVC checks the object cannot yet cash, so to speak...

Comment: @Kendall: that may be true, but it is still not common to release via the ivar, AFAICT. I would assign `[NSIndexPath alloc]` to a variable and then release through that, and not through the ivar.

Comment: It is common to release from the ivar in dealloc, for the same reasons you don't want to use the property in init (in fact I have seen some VERY nasty bugs as a direct result of people using the property to release in dealloc).  In init you never need to release because by definition nothing can be set, and in fact the operation would be wasted.  I don't see why you wouldn't just set it to the iVar since you need to keep it retained, and it's better as noted not to use the property setter.

Answer (score 6):

In init you are really supposed to use the ivars for setting directly:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    _indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

Perhaps that would cure the issue?  It would follow convention.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that by using the setter method, the compiler cannot guarantee that the same object you passed to the setter will actually be assigned to the backing ivar. After all, your setter method may do all sorts of strange stuff, least of which could include making a copy of the passed object.

In other words, the compiler cannot guarantee that `self.indexPath == _indexPath`, so your call to release may be on a different object than the one you got from the `init` method. Thus, it gives you a warning that your memory management may be incorrect, which is appropriate.

Thus, you need to guarantee that you're calling `release` on the same object that you passed to the setter. In short:

```
NSIndexPath *tmpPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
self.indexPath = tmpPath;

[tmpPath release];           // This is the only correct way to do it.
// [self.indexPath release]; // WRONG! May not be the same object as tmpPath
// [_indexPath release];     // WRONG! May not be the same object as tmpPath
```

As others have mentioned, though, in an init method it's generally better to just assign to the ivar directly. Thus:

```
_indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
```

Comment: if the property method is retain, the two objects will always be the same.

Comment: @jyavenard: Assuming you haven't overridden the setter method, yes. And assuming this isn't an instance of a subclass which overrode the setter method. And assuming nobody swizzled the setter method. Point is, the compiler can't make those assumptions; it doesn't have the information to make that guarantee at compile-time, which is why you get a compile-time warning that there may be a problem.

Comment: And, as you point out, if the property were declared as 'copy' instead of 'retain', the memory management could be incorrect even with just the synthesized setter method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSIndexPath *tmpPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
self.indexPath = tmpPath;
[tmpPath release];
```

Answer (score 2):

The static analyzer is probably just looking at that one line as it is not clever enough to realise that you were actually attempting to rectify the issue.

I would use this pattern

```
NSIndexPath *tmpPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
self.indexPath = tmpPath;
[tmpPath release];
```

More in depth explanation. So when the analyzer looks at the line

```
self.indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
```

It see's the +1 retain from this part

```
[[NSIndexPath alloc] init]
```

and it see that the `self.indexPath` is compiled to

```
[self setIndexPath:[[NSIndexPath alloc] init]];
```

This method (if auto generated by `@synthesize`) will probably look like this

```
- (void)setIndexPathL(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_indexPath != indexPath) {
        [_indexPath release];
        _indexPath = [indexPath retain];
    }
}
```

So now the analyzer see's that there is another `retain` on indexPath.

So that's 2 x +1 retain and it can only assume that you will release once in the dealloc.

Comment: The reason the analyzer doesn't catch the release is that the setter method *may* have assigned a different object to the backing ivar than the passed object. Notably, if you passed an invalid object, it might set the backing ivar to nil. Thus, `_indexPath` is not guaranteed to be the same object as `tmpPath` in your example, which is why the analyzer warns about it.